# adding an image to the dom and performing .load

Tags: jquery, image, load

ok, so this is weird.
the following code works in all browsers, except in IE9 when chaning it to IE8 in the developer tools.

```
var img = $('<img/>').load(function (e) {
    $('.md').append(e.target);
}).attr({ 'id': 'imgprofile', 'src': "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/28/HelloWorld.svg/512px-HelloWorld.svg.png", 'style': 'border:2px solid #a8a7a7;' });
```

here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/RZeY5/5/

as you can see, when the .load event is completed (only in IE8 Mode)
instead of adding the image to dom, something happens and the whole screen goes white (in the jsfiddle example, the iframe is going white).

after spending hours and hours on trying to understand whats wrong with my code (this is a very long JS file....)
i managed to take it down to the `$('.md').append(e.target);` line but i do not know what to do now...
is this my fault? is this JQuery fault? is it IE8 fault?
what can i do to solve this issue?

please notice, you MUST be in IE8 mode for the 'bug' to happen.

EDIT **
i just so that it happens also in IE7 mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those IEs, the `e.target === document` and `e.target` is not appropriate anyway, you should use `e.currentTarget`or `this`.

http://jsfiddle.net/RZeY5/7/

Those older IEs use `srcElement`, which happens to be `null` in this case and jQuery assigns it to `document` in this case.

```
    // Fix target property, if necessary (#1925, IE 6/7/8 & Safari2)
    if ( !event.target ) {
        event.target = originalEvent.srcElement || document;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldnt JQuery handle this? after all, CrossBrowser is kind of their thing... also, how does you fix work? originalEvent is unknown.

Comment: @Dementic it's handling it by setting it to `document`, otherwise it would be `null`. Though `.currentTarget` would be better than `document` I guess but I think they have their reasons? :P

Comment: btw, even due changing 'e.target' to 'this' "fixes" it, it breaks the rest of my script, as if the '.load' is not there.

Comment: @Dementic that's weird. The jsfiddle is working fine. Can you reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: i have JCrop running on that image, after its .load event. fixing it with 'this' makes JCrop unusable.

Comment: @Dementic I don't know what JCrop is. Is it providing its own .load event or something? Does using `e.currentTarget` work?

Comment: `e.currentTarget` works the same as `this`, JCrop is a JQuery Plugin to crop images, i might look for another way to dynamicly add an image and attach an onload event to it.

Comment: i managed to solve this with plain js .... creating an image in memory and attaching an onload even, works like a charm in all browsers. thx for your help anyways :)